# Spring how to use non manged external libry class in spring context

Tags: java, spring

I have spring configuration class.In that i have a class ServerConfigurationService which is external libry class and it is not marked as a spring bean.ServerConfigurationService class is used to read properies in static way as follow

> System.out.println(ServerConfigurationService.getString(
>               "pii.encryption.cipherString", null));

ServerConfigurationService.java class located in external libry

```
public class ServerConfigurationService
{
    public final static String CURRENT_SERVER_URL = org.sakaiproject.component.api.ServerConfigurationService.CURRENT_SERVER_URL;

    public final static String CURRENT_PORTAL_PATH = org.sakaiproject.component.api.ServerConfigurationService.CURRENT_PORTAL_PATH;

   /**
     * Access the component instance: special cover only method.
     * 
     * @return the component instance.
     */
    public static org.sakaipro
```

............................................................

```
}
```

but this print null value with following stack trace.

> java.lang.Exception: traceback    at
>   org.sakaiproject.util.NoisierDefaultListableBeanFactory.destroySingletons(NoisierDefaultListableBeanFactory.java:94)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.destroyBeans(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1006)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:551)
>     at
>   org.sakaiproject.component.impl.SpringCompMgr.init(SpringCompMgr.java:160)
>     at
>   org.sakaiproject.component.cover.ComponentManager.getInstance(ComponentManager.java:98)
>     at
>   org.sakaiproject.component.cover.ComponentManager.get(ComponentManager.java:107)
>     at
>   org.sakaiproject.component.cover.ServerConfigurationService.getInstance(ServerConfigurationService.java:54)
>     at
>   org.sakaiproject.component.cover.ServerConfigurationService.getString(ServerConfigurationService.java:206)
>   2018-05-03 09:58:11,701  WARN main
>   org.sakaiproject.component.impl.SpringCompMgr - Configuration: Unable
>   to get and dump out the registered server config values because no
>   ServerConfigurationService is available - this is OK if this is part
>   of a test, this is very bad otherwise 2018-05-03 09:58:11,701  WARN
>   main org.sakaiproject.component.impl.SpringCompMgr -
>   get(org.sakaiproject.component.api.ServerConfigurationService):

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "org.sakaiproject.log.api")
    @Configuration
    public class SpringCryptoContext {



        public SpringCryptoContext() {

        }


        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

            ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(
                    SpringCryptoContext.class);

            System.out.println(ServerConfigurationService.getString(
                "pii.encryption.cipherString", null));

    }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should register your class as bean in your application. because if you try to inject your class inside any other bean (i.e. controller/service) it wont be available as its object will not be available in spring container.

Declare your custom class as bean in your configuration file as below:

```
@Bean
public ServerConfigurationService getServerConfigurationService(){
// configure your object.
}
```